# Write to console only if any() function returns false

Tags: python, python-3.x

Long time haven't used python, so don't laugh.

I have two lists which I am comparing:

```
list_1, list_2 = [sorted(l, key=itemgetter("someKey"))
                  for l in (list_1, list_2)]

pairs = zip(list_1, list_2)
return any(x != y for x, y in pairs)
```

How to best modify the code so that when it find a pair that does not match (2 items doesn't equal each other), it will print out this NOT matching pair.

I know it could be done using for loop, but is there a better simpler way here ?

Comment: You code is invalid (`return` statement outside of function), and you should provide example input and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

The least verbose way I can think of is probably

```
return next(((x, y) for (x, y) in pairs if x != y), 'All Pairs Match')
```

what this does is pipe the generator comprehension `(x, y) for (x, y) in pairs if x != y` into `next()`, which will return the first element it produces (i.e. the first case for which x != y), or if that never happens, will return the default `'All Pairs Match'` (or whatever else it is you want to return if the two lists are the same).

`next()` is designed mostly to be used inside `while` loops for taking items one-by-one from an iterator at need, but we can also use it for things like this when we only need to know the first element in a collection that meets a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a return, I assume you have a function definition like

```
def foo(list_1, list_2):
    pairs = zip(list_1, list_2)
    return any(x != y for x, y in pairs)
```

Once the function returns, it's too late to see what made `any` return `False`, so we'll have to save the return value before actually returning.

We can, however, make use of assignment expressions to save the *last* values assigned to `x` and `y` before `any` stopped iterating over `pairs`.

```
def foo(list_1, list_2):
    pairs = zip(list_1, list_2)
    if rv := any((x0:=x) != (y0:=y) for x, y in pairs):
        print(x0, y0)
    return rv
```

`x0` and `y0` repeatedly get assigned new values as the iteration proceeds, but are *not* local to the generator expression as `x` and `y` are, so we can look at there values after `any` returns. (Likewise, `rv` saves the return value of `any` so that regardless of what `any` returns, `foo` can return that value after the `if` statement completes.)

Use cases like this are precisely *why* [assignment expressions are scoped the way they are](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target).

> There is one special case: **an assignment expression** occurring in a list, set or dict comprehension or **in a generator expression** (below collectively referred to as “comprehensions”) **binds the target in the containing scope**, honoring a nonlocal or global declaration for the target in that scope, if one exists.

*not* the scope of the generator expression itself.